# as.factor not working: turning characters into integers instead

Tags: r

I am new to R, so it's possible this is all operator error, but I cannot for the life of me get as.factor to work in my code. I have it working earlier in my script, but for this one particular task, I cannot get it to function properly.

I'm trying to turn a column of characters ("Disaster_Cause") into a factor, so I can then turn it into an integer (an index variable). However, the as.factor function is not working (nor is as_factor or any of the dplyr recommendations in other stack overflow threads). Instead, as.factor skips straight to an integer, and not even in the way I'm looking for (three separate integers, one for each cause)--just one "integer" for all three, which actually is just the same character cells.

Some friends of mine were having a similar issue earlier this quarter. Could it maybe be a glitch in R Studio or rstan?

Here's my code:

```
data2 <- read.csv("Disaster_by_Cause_Year_v1.csv", header = T)
D2 <- as.data.frame(data2)
colnames(D2) <- c( "Impact_Year", "Disaster_Cause" )
typeof("Disaster_Cause") # shows as character
levels("Disaster_Cause") # character, so shows as NULL
D2$cause <- as.factor( D2$Disaster_Cause )
typeof(D2$cause) #skips straight to integer
levels( D2$cause ) #integer is [1] "cause1" "cause2" "cause3" as characters, not integers or three separate factors/integers, as it should be
```

I've re-downloaded the csv file and scoured it for typos, but all seems fine on that front. I've also tried different names for the data file, data frame, factor, etc and also tried just making the Disaster Causes integers in the original data. I've also tried using other ways to turn characters into factors, but they all do the same thing. Using as.factor works on the source data this is from earlier in the code, so I'm really stumped here.

Any insight anyone might have would be amazing.

Here's a google drive link to the data if that's helpful: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1szlTGQVYb00SzutAYeKwF1-6BoED_p8Hpf1J0GJjUS0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to check `class(D2$cause)` instead of `typeof` as the storage mode of factor is integer. i.e. `as.integer(factor(letters[1:3]))`

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong in what you're seeing.  Factors are stored as integers, so that's what `typeof(D2$cause)` should show.  You can use `is.factor(D2$cause)` or `class(D2$cause)` to see you've got a factor.

Comment: Wow, I feel like an enormous dingbat. Thank you so much. Sure enough, it's been a factor this whole time. Glad I'm not going insane. Thanks again!